# Authorization_RequestDenied , message : Insufficient privileges to complete the operation

Tags: flutter, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm tring to get data of signed in user from microsoft azure using microsoft graph api,
i'm getting access token and also login successfully,

but i'm getting error as : "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."

My Code

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:aad_oauth/aad_oauth.dart';
import 'package:aad_oauth/model/config.dart';
import 'package:exim_bank_leave_app/Utils/AppTheme.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'Screens/Listing.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

   @override
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return MaterialApp(
     debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
     theme: MyTheme.darkTheme(context),
     home: MyHomePage(),
      );
   }
  }

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  static var user;
  static final Config config = Config(
  tenant: 'f6------------------38',
  clientId: 'cba-----------------f5',
  scope: 'openid profile offline_access',
  redirectUri: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient',
  ); 

  static final AadOAuth oauth = AadOAuth(config);
 @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
   }

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
 SharedPreferences prefs;
 static final String accessToken = accessToken;
 var token;

  @override
  void initState() {
  super.initState();
  loadData();
  }

   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  // adjust window size for browser login
  var screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
  var rectSize =
    Rect.fromLTWH(0.0, 25.0, screenSize.width, screenSize.height - 25);
  MyHomePage.oauth.setWebViewScreenSize(rectSize);

    return Scaffold(
    body: Container(),
    );
  }

 loadData() async {
 var auth = MyHomePage.oauth;
await auth.login();
var accessToken = await auth.getAccessToken();

Navigator.pushReplacement(
    context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Listing()));

prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
while (prefs == null || accessToken == null) continue;
final String idToken = await auth.getIdToken();

setState(() {
  prefs.setString('token', idToken);
 });

 print('Token $accessToken');
 final graphResponse = await http.get('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me',
    headers: {HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: "Bearer $accessToken"});
 print(graphResponse.body.toString());
 print(graphResponse.statusCode);
}

 static void logout() async {
 await MyHomePage.oauth.logout();
 }
}
```

Error : I/flutter (29743): {"error":{"code":"Authorization_RequestDenied","message":"Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.","innerError":{"date":"2021-10-04T10:28:54","request-id":"3b12c615-47f1-4d07-ab4e-b6f4907a5b11","client-request-id":"3b12c615-47f1-4d07-ab4e-b6f4907a5b11"}}}

Comment: Have you tried to run this `get` request with Postman, by adding the auth header manually? Does it work?

Comment: Yes, i tried but it not worked in Postman error showing as :" Access token validation failure. Invalid audience."

Comment: Try adding scope `User.Read` and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your code '`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me`' you are  using the  `/me`

When Calling the `/me`   endpoint requires a signed-in user and therefore a **delegated permission**. Application permissions are not supported when using the `/me` endpoint .So Add the **Delegated permission** to call ApI

Delegated permissions are

```
User.Read, 
User.ReadWrite, 
User.ReadBasic.All, 
User.Read.All,
User.ReadWrite.All, 
Directory.Read.All, 
Directory.ReadWrite.All,
Directory.AccessAsUser.All
```

To add the permission

**1)**  Under an application's **API permissions** page, choose **Add a permission**.

[image]

**2)**   select **Microsoft Graph.**

[image]

**3)** Choose the **Delegated permission**. And **Search all the permission** and Click on the **Add Permission**.

[image]

For more details refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)